# What is the purpose of this box behind the yoke on a 737?

Tags: boeing-737, feature-identification

I was looking at the 737 cockpit when I found this apparatus behind the yoke. I have never seen it before and I have no idea what is does. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean the yellowish handle?

Comment: Why the close vote?

Answer (score 6):

The image (beige handle) is a Rudder Crank Unit (*source*: [Flaps2approch.com](https://www.flaps2approach.com/journal/2017/3/24/oem-rudder-crank-unit.html)). Rotating the beige handle moves/adjusts the rudder pedals fore and aft.

[image]